# oauth in kivy-android app using jnius

Tags: android, oauth, kivy

I want to get redirecting url from my kivy-android `WebView`. In Android, it can be achieved by overriding `WebViewClient`. But I don't know how to do it in kivy app. I tried to extend `WebViewClient` to create `OAuthWebViewClient` in my kivy app, but it is causing crash on Android device.

Comment: why does it crush?
did you check `adb catlog` ?

Comment: while using OAuthWebViewClient with webview i am getting these error in the log.
dlopen("/data/data/org.myapp.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.myapp.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
dlopen("/data/data/org.myapp.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.myapp.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so"
whereas it works perfectly fine with WebViewClient instead of OAuthWebViewClient. I am not sure why it is giving these not found errors.